# Setting alternating background-color in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-color

This simple style works to provide alternating background-color[s] in my tables in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in IE 11 (and, I presume, earlier versions). In the latter, no color is there and my background-image shows through.

```
.recordtable tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #eee;}

.recordtable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

Can I get this to work in IE? Thank you.

Comment: I just tried and it works perfectly. Can you provide a jsFiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Of course, it does not work if you have missing TDs (and possibly empty ones).

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with IE in the past when trying to style a `tr` element.  Try styling the child `td` elements instead, like so:

```
.recordtable tr:nth-child(even) td {background-color: #eee;}

.recordtable tr:nth-child(odd) td {background-color: #ddd;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using CSS and jQuery

CSS:

```
.recordtable  tr.even{background-color: #eee;}    
.recordtable  tr.odd{background-color: #ddd;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".recordtable  tr:nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    $(".recordtable  tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
});
```